# execution reverted: 27 HELP?

Tags: solidity, remix, error, flash-loans

I have a simple flashloan solidity code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import {FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase.sol";
import {IPoolAddressesProvider} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

contract FlashLoan is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    address payable owner;

    constructor(address _addressProvider)
        FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider))
    {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
        This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 premium,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        //
        // This contract now has the funds requested.
        // Your logic goes here.
        //

        // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
        // the flashloaned amount + premiums.
        // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay
        // these amounts.

        // Approve the Pool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
        uint256 amountOwed = amount + premium;
        IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), amountOwed);

        return true;
    }

    function requestFlashLoan( address _token, uint256 _amount) public{
        IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this)) >= 1000000;
        address receiverAddress = address(this);
        address asset = _token;
        uint256 amount = _amount;
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        POOL.flashLoanSimple(
            receiverAddress,
            asset,
            amount,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }

    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "Only the contract owner can call this function"
        );
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

when I try to execute requestFlashLoan Function and I pass USDC token address
//requestFlashLoan(0x65aFADD39029741B3b8f0756952C74678c9cEC93,1000000)
and amount
it return this error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted: 27
{
"originalError": {
"code": 3,
"data": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023237000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"message": "execution reverted: 27"
}
}
```

this contract has enough tokens to execute that function can anyone please help me understand why does this happen ?

Answer (score 1):

the 27 error description looks like this in aave:

```
  string public constant RESERVE_INACTIVE = '27'; // 'Action requires an active reserve'
```

Which network you are in?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same issue and i'm on network goerli from the 27 error ```'Action requires an active reserve'``` i assume this is talking about the reserve in the simulation dex contract made (Dex.sol) in which I (and i assume the op) put 1500 usdc and 1500 dai into dex.sol as liquidity. So i'm not sure what the issue is :/